# Web Audio API доступ к аудио элементу видео плеера, который замучен (video.js)

Tags: javascript, videojs

Использую следующий код:

player.on('volumechange', function(event) {

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
if(player.muted() == false){

  var myMeterElement = document.getElementById('my-peak-meter');
   var myAudio = document.querySelector('#videojs-overlay-player_html5_api');
  var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext);
  var sourceNode = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(myAudio);
  sourceNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
  var meterNode = webAudioPeakMeter.createMeterNode(sourceNode, audioCtx);
  webAudioPeakMeter.createMeter(myMeterElement, meterNode, {});
} 

}, 0);
});
```

В div наложенный на видео графически отображается уровень звука видео.

Моя задача добиться отображения уровня звука при замученом видеоплеере. То-есть, из колонок звук не играет, но графически отображается.

На данный момент я смог достичь:

1. При открытии страницы видеоплеер video.js автоматически запускается (будучи замученым).
2. При нажать на анмут появляется оверлей с графическим уровнем звука.

Мне необходимо, чтобы графический оверлей появляется при запуске плеера в замученом режиме.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как этого можно достичь?

Comment: Что такое замученный режим?

Comment: Замученный - Muted @Олег

Comment: Я код пока толком не разобрал, но может в замютированном режиме не от куда браться данным для отображения уровня?

Comment: Попробуйте вариант, чтобы видеоплеер запускался не замютированном, а потом кнопкой включать звук, приводя в действие сроку sourceNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);

Comment: @Олег Ввиду современной браузерной политики, видеоплеер не запускается автоматически в режиме вещания звука. В любом случае, мне необходимо одновременно отображать уровни звука двух разных стримов на одной странице. WEB AUDIO API как я понимаю, может работать только с тем, что играет в браузере. Поэтому, нет возможности разделения на потоки. Вероятно, мне нужен какой-то скрипт, который разбирает конкретно файл стрима и анализирует. Пока такого инструмента не нашел...